# How to launch a dialog box with a button when Game is complete?

Tags: java, android

Please help with the following code - I need a dialog box with a button to appear when the game puzzle is completed. Thank you!

Here's the code:

Sudoku.java

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   private static final String TAG = "Sudoku";

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
      View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
      continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
      View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
      newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
      View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
      aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
      View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
      exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
   }


   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      Music.play(this, R.raw.main);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      Music.stop(this);
   }



   public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.continue_button:
         startGame(Game.DIFFICULTY_CONTINUE);
         break;
         // ...

      case R.id.about_button:
         Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
         startActivity(i);
         break;
      // More buttons go here (if any) ...
      case R.id.new_button:
         openNewGameDialog();
         break;
      case R.id.exit_button:
         finish();
         break;

      }
   }


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.settings:
         startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));
         return true;
      // More items go here (if any) ...
      }
      return false;
   }

   /** Ask the user what difficulty level they want */
   private void openNewGameDialog() {
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
           .setTitle(R.string.new_game_title)
           .setItems(R.array.difficulty,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,
                     int i) {
                  startGame(i);
               }
            })
           .show();
   }

   /** Start a new game with the given difficulty level */
   private void startGame(int i) {
      Log.d(TAG, "clicked on " + i);
      Intent intent = new Intent(Sudoku.this, Game.class);
      intent.putExtra(Game.KEY_DIFFICULTY, i);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

Game.Java

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Game extends Activity {
   private static final String TAG = "Sudoku";

   public static final String KEY_DIFFICULTY =
      "org.example.sudoku.difficulty";

   private static final String PREF_PUZZLE = "puzzle" ;

   public static final int DIFFICULTY_EASY = 0;
   public static final int DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM = 1;
   public static final int DIFFICULTY_HARD = 2;

   protected static final int DIFFICULTY_CONTINUE = -1;


   private int puzzle[] = new int[9 * 9];

   private final String easyPuzzle =
      "360000000004230800000004200" +
      "070460003820000014500013020" +
      "001900000007048300000000045";
   private final String mediumPuzzle =
      "650000070000506000014000005" +
      "007009000002314700000700800" +
      "500000630000201000030000097";
   private final String hardPuzzle =
      "009000000080605020501078000" +
      "000000700706040102004000000" +
      "000720903090301080000000600";

   private PuzzleView puzzleView;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

      int diff = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY,
            DIFFICULTY_EASY);
      puzzle = getPuzzle(diff);
      calculateUsedTiles();

      puzzleView = new PuzzleView(this);
      setContentView(puzzleView);
      puzzleView.requestFocus();


      // ...
      // If the activity is restarted, do a continue next time
      getIntent().putExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY, DIFFICULTY_CONTINUE);
   }


   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      Music.play(this, R.raw.game);
   }


   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
      Music.stop(this);

      // Save the current puzzle
      getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(PREF_PUZZLE,
            toPuzzleString(puzzle)).commit();
   }



   /** Given a difficulty level, come up with a new puzzle */
   private int[] getPuzzle(int diff) {
      String puz;
      switch (diff) {
      case DIFFICULTY_CONTINUE:
         puz = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString(PREF_PUZZLE,
               easyPuzzle);
         break;
         // ...

      case DIFFICULTY_HARD:
         puz = hardPuzzle;
         break;
      case DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM:
         puz = mediumPuzzle;
         break;
      case DIFFICULTY_EASY:
      default:
         puz = easyPuzzle;
         break;

      }
      return fromPuzzleString(puz);
   }


   /** Convert an array into a puzzle string */
   static private String toPuzzleString(int[] puz) {
      StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
      for (int element : puz) {
         buf.append(element);
      }
      return buf.toString();
   }

   /** Convert a puzzle string into an array */
   static protected int[] fromPuzzleString(String string) {
      int[] puz = new int[string.length()];
      for (int i = 0; i < puz.length; i++) {
         puz[i] = string.charAt(i) - '0';
      }
      return puz;
   }

   /** Return the tile at the given coordinates */
   private int getTile(int x, int y) {
      return puzzle[y * 9 + x];
   }

   /** Change the tile at the given coordinates */
   private void setTile(int x, int y, int value) {
      puzzle[y * 9 + x] = value;
   }

   /** Return a string for the tile at the given coordinates */
   protected String getTileString(int x, int y) {
      int v = getTile(x, y);
      if (v == 0)
         return "";
      else
         return String.valueOf(v);
   }

   /** Change the tile only if it's a valid move */
   protected boolean setTileIfValid(int x, int y, int value) {
      int tiles[] = getUsedTiles(x, y);
      if (value != 0) {
         for (int tile : tiles) {
            if (tile == value)
               return false;
         }
      }
      setTile(x, y, value);
      calculateUsedTiles();
      return true;
   }

   /** Open the keypad if there are any valid moves */
   protected void showKeypadOrError(int x, int y) {
      int tiles[] = getUsedTiles(x, y);
      if (tiles.length == 9) {
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
               R.string.no_moves_label, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
         toast.show();
      } else {
         Log.d(TAG, "showKeypad: used=" + toPuzzleString(tiles));
         Dialog v = new Keypad(this, tiles, puzzleView);
         v.show();
      }
   }

   /** Cache of used tiles */
   private final int used[][][] = new int[9][9][];

   /** Return cached used tiles visible from the given coords */
   protected int[] getUsedTiles(int x, int y) {
      return used[x][y];
   }

   /** Compute the two dimensional array of used tiles */
   private void calculateUsedTiles() {
      for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
         for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            used[x][y] = calculateUsedTiles(x, y);
            // Log.d(TAG, "used[" + x + "][" + y + "] = "
            // + toPuzzleString(used[x][y]));
         }
      }
   }

   /** Compute the used tiles visible from this position */
   private int[] calculateUsedTiles(int x, int y) {
      int c[] = new int[9];
      // horizontal
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         if (i == y)
            continue;
         int t = getTile(x, i);
         if (t != 0)
            c[t - 1] = t;
      }
      // vertical
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         if (i == x)
            continue;
         int t = getTile(i, y);
         if (t != 0)
            c[t - 1] = t;
      }
      // same cell block
      int startx = (x / 3) * 3;
      int starty = (y / 3) * 3;
      for (int i = startx; i < startx + 3; i++) {
         for (int j = starty; j < starty + 3; j++) {
            if (i == x && j == y)
               continue;
            int t = getTile(i, j);
            if (t != 0)
               c[t - 1] = t;
         }
      }
      // compress
      int nused = 0;
      for (int t : c) {
         if (t != 0)
            nused++;
      }
      int c1[] = new int[nused];
      nused = 0;
      for (int t : c) {
         if (t != 0)
            c1[nused++] = t;
      }
      return c1;
   }

}
```

PuzzleView.java

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Paint.FontMetrics;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;


public class PuzzleView extends View {

   private static final String TAG = "Sudoku";


   private static final String SELX = "selX"; 
   private static final String SELY = "selY";
   private static final String VIEW_STATE = "viewState";
   private static final int ID = 42; 


   private float width;    // width of one tile
   private float height;   // height of one tile
   private int selX;       // X index of selection
   private int selY;       // Y index of selection
   private final Rect selRect = new Rect();

   private final Game game;

   public PuzzleView(Context context) {

      super(context);
      this.game = (Game) context;
      setFocusable(true);
      setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

      // ...
      setId(ID); 
   }

   @Override
   protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() { 
      Parcelable p = super.onSaveInstanceState();
      Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putInt(SELX, selX);
      bundle.putInt(SELY, selY);
      bundle.putParcelable(VIEW_STATE, p);
      return bundle;
   }
   @Override
   protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) { 
      Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
      Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
      select(bundle.getInt(SELX), bundle.getInt(SELY));
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(VIEW_STATE));
      return;
   }


   @Override
   protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
      width = w / 9f;
      height = h / 9f;
      getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
      Log.d(TAG, "onSizeChanged: width " + width + ", height "
            + height);
      super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      // Draw the background...
      Paint background = new Paint();
      background.setColor(getResources().getColor(
            R.color.puzzle_background));
      canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);


      // Draw the board...

      // Define colors for the grid lines
      Paint dark = new Paint();
      dark.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_dark));

      Paint hilite = new Paint();
      hilite.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_hilite));

      Paint light = new Paint();
      light.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_light));

      // Draw the minor grid lines
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height,
               light);
         canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height
               + 1, hilite);
         canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(),
               light);
         canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1,
               getHeight(), hilite);
      }

      // Draw the major grid lines
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         if (i % 3 != 0)
            continue;
         canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height,
               dark);
         canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height
               + 1, hilite);
         canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), dark);
         canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1,
               getHeight(), hilite);
      }

      // Draw the numbers...
      // Define color and style for numbers
      Paint foreground = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      foreground.setColor(getResources().getColor(
            R.color.puzzle_foreground));
      foreground.setStyle(Style.FILL);
      foreground.setTextSize(height * 0.75f);
      foreground.setTextScaleX(width / height);
      foreground.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

      // Draw the number in the center of the tile
      FontMetrics fm = foreground.getFontMetrics();
      // Centering in X: use alignment (and X at midpoint)
      float x = width / 2;
      // Centering in Y: measure ascent/descent first
      float y = height / 2 - (fm.ascent + fm.descent) / 2;
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            canvas.drawText(this.game.getTileString(i, j), i
                  * width + x, j * height + y, foreground);
         }
      }


      if (Prefs.getHints(getContext())) {
         // Draw the hints...

         // Pick a hint color based on #moves left
         Paint hint = new Paint();
         int c[] = { getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_hint_0),
               getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_hint_1),
               getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_hint_2), };
         Rect r = new Rect();
         for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
               int movesleft = 9 - game.getUsedTiles(i, j).length;
               if (movesleft < c.length) {
                  getRect(i, j, r);
                  hint.setColor(c[movesleft]);
                  canvas.drawRect(r, hint);
               }
            }
         }

      }


      // Draw the selection...
      Log.d(TAG, "selRect=" + selRect);
      Paint selected = new Paint();
      selected.setColor(getResources().getColor(
            R.color.puzzle_selected));
      canvas.drawRect(selRect, selected);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
         return super.onTouchEvent(event);

      select((int) (event.getX() / width),
            (int) (event.getY() / height));
      game.showKeypadOrError(selX, selY);
      Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: x " + selX + ", y " + selY);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown: keycode=" + keyCode + ", event="
            + event);
      switch (keyCode) {
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
         select(selX, selY - 1);
         break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
         select(selX, selY + 1);
         break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
         select(selX - 1, selY);
         break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
         select(selX + 1, selY);
         break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE: setSelectedTile(0); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:     setSelectedTile(1); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:     setSelectedTile(2); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:     setSelectedTile(3); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4:     setSelectedTile(4); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5:     setSelectedTile(5); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_6:     setSelectedTile(6); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_7:     setSelectedTile(7); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_8:     setSelectedTile(8); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9:     setSelectedTile(9); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
         game.showKeypadOrError(selX, selY);
         break;
      default:
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
      }
      return true;
   }

   public void setSelectedTile(int tile) {
      if (game.setTileIfValid(selX, selY, tile)) {
         invalidate();// may change hints
      } else {
         // Number is not valid for this tile
         Log.d(TAG, "setSelectedTile: invalid: " + tile);
         startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(game,
               R.anim.shake));
      }
   }

   private void select(int x, int y) {
      invalidate(selRect);
      selX = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8);
      selY = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), 8);
      getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
      invalidate(selRect);
   }

   private void getRect(int x, int y, Rect rect) {
      rect.set((int) (x * width), (int) (y * height), (int) (x
            * width + width), (int) (y * height + height));
   }

   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an AlertDialog?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Comment: Thanks but does not help me as am new to programming. Can someone please give the code to make this happen. thanks again.